# cordova iOS notification don't work in foreground

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, alert, foreground

I'm using Cordova and the plugin phonegap-plugin-push,
when my app is in foreground I don't see the notification alert.
What I have to do?
(I know the way to do it on Android platform (setting "forceShow": true in the method init of PushNotification) but this works only for Android)
Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Thank you to all! I solved  using the method push.finish() of cordova plugin and now the banner is showed, but when it disappear the notification doesn't store in the list of notification to read of the device and this is a problem! Any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If u don't want to touch ios native things, then you can display your own custmize html/css Banner (like iOS push Baner) in following method :

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    If(platform == "iOS" && data.additionalData.foreground){
    // Show your Baner here
// U can also define call back on clicking of that banner
//Like navigation to respective page or close that banner
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved in a similar way using the method push.finish() and now the banner is showed, but when it disappear the notification doesn't store in the list of notification to read of the device and this is a problem! Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: I din't understand your new problem properly. But i would like to give some more information which may help you .
1. First of all this banner will be a part of your application web view, so it will never store in the list of native notification in notification center. 
2. when the banner will disappear, then it won't be part of your application anymore.
3. Instead of banner you can display local notification also using **cordova-plugin-local-notifications**

Answer (score 0):

Denise,

Notification doesn't work in the foreground. It only works in the background. Do handle it in the foreground you need to implement the logic in the delegate method.
Below is the Objective C code snippet to show the notification in the foreground.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    //self.textView.text = [userInfo description];
    // We can determine whether an application is launched as a result of the user tapping the action
    // button or whether the notification was delivered to the already-running application by examining
    // the application state.

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        // Nothing to do if applicationState is Inactive, the iOS already displayed an alert view.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your App name received this notification while it was running:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }    
}
```

It will help you for your problem.

Comment: thank you for your reply! But I'm using Cordova, you know If is a way to do that in cordova modifying the javascript?

Comment: Its safe way @Denise. You can use it freely and it doesn't cause any application rejection. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In iOS if your app is in foreground, push notification alert will not show. To achieve it, you should write code for alert in push notification receive delegate if your application is in foreground. To know application state in iOS this is the code.

```
+(BOOL) runningInForeground
{
UIApplicationState state = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;

return state == UIApplicationStateActive;

}
```

Comment: @iamgam  thank you for your reply! But I'm using Cordova, you know If is a way to do that in cordova modifying the javascript?or it's possible only with native code?

Comment: @Denise, Please read this [link](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) '// iOS
function onNotificationAPN (event) {
    if ( event.alert )
    {
        navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }

    if ( event.sound )
    {
        var snd = new Media(event.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if ( event.badge )
    {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
    }
}'

Comment: If this helps you, please up vote and accept answer.